# Asymptotic approximation for $E[X_n]$ where $\{X_n\}$ converges in probability to a constant $\mu$?

Tags: probability-theory, asymptotics, expected-value

I have a sequence of bounded random variables $\{X_n\}$, i.e. $|X_n| \le C$ for all $n$.

Suppose this sequence convergences in probability to a constant $\mu$ with known rate of convergence, e.g.
$$
X_n - \mu = o_p\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg), \quad \quad \quad \quad \text{or} \quad \quad \quad \quad X_n - \mu = O_p\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg).
$$

Suppose also that $\{X_n\}$ is uniformly integrable. Then $X_n$ converges in expectation to $\mu$. But what about the asymptotic rate of convergence of the expectation? Do the $O_p$ and/or $o_p$ rates of convergence translate into a corresponding rate of convergence for the expectation? For example, do they allows us to say something like the following: As $n \to \infty$,
$$
E[X_n] = \mu + O\bigg(\frac{1}{n}\bigg).
$$

Answer (score 1):

I borrow the argument of shrinking bumps (centered at zero, of width $1/\sqrt{n}$ and constant height $1$) from [Convergence in probability implies boundedness in $L^1$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1333436/290189) to answer your question.

WLOG, assume that $\mu = 0$.  Consider $((0,1],\mathcal{B}((0,1]),\text{Leb})$, and
the family of random variables $X_n(\omega) := 1_{(0,1/\sqrt{n})}(\omega)$ for $\omega \in (0,1]$.  Fix $\epsilon \in (0,1)$ (independent of $n$).  $X_n$ is an indicator function, so we write $X_n$ instead of $|X_n|$.

Check that $nX_n = O_p(1)$.  (As the choice of $\epsilon$ doesn't depend on $n$, it's also $o_p(1)$.)  Observe that the value of $X_n$ is either $0$ or $1$.

\begin{align}
P(nX_n \ge \epsilon) &= P(X_n \ge \epsilon/n) = 1/\sqrt{n} \to 0 \text{ as } n \to +\infty, \\
\text{but } E[nX_n] &= E[n1_{(0,1/\sqrt{n})}] = n (1/\sqrt{n}) = \sqrt{n} \to \infty.
\end{align}
Hence $o_p$ and $O_p$ don't translate to $o$ and $O$ in expected values respectively.

Comment: But is your $\{X_n\}$ uniformly integrable? Convergence in probability to $\mu$ combined with uniform integrability of the sequence of random variables implies convergence in expectation to $\mu$.

Comment: Yes, as $X_n$ is just a family of indicator functions, so it's uniformly bounded.    You've raised a good point.  You've put $1/n$ inside the bracket, so becomes another story.  That might indicate that $(nX_n)_n$ isn't UI.  To verify that, say we have a large integer $N$.  Once we worked out expected large absolute deviation $$\sup_{n \in \Bbb{N}} E \left[nX_n 1_{\{nX_n \ge N\}}\right]$$ in terms of $N$, we'll take $N \to +\infty$ to see.

Comment: I meant to say $\{nX_n\}$ as that is the sequence you consider. This sequence doesn't correspond to the one in my original question. I defined a sequence $\{X_n\}$ that is uniformly integrable and converges in probability to $\mu$. So I already know it converges to $\mu$ in expectation based on that. So for my situation where we have convergence in both probability and expectation to $\mu$ I am asking can we find a rate of convergence in expectation based on the rate of convergence in probability.

Comment: I see.  I've responded to the last prompt by showing that you can't copy and paste what's in the bracket from $o_p$ to $O_p$.

Comment: ...............

Comment: @sonicboom Why did you replace your previous comment by `.`?

Comment: I didn't ask about copy and pasting from $o_p$ to $O_p$. I asked: when we have a sequence which is uniformly integrable and converges in probability to $\mu$, and thus converges in expectation to $\mu$, can the $O_p$ or $o_p$ rate of convergence in probability be used to obtain a, possibly different, $O$ rate of convergence in expectation. This is not the situation considered in your post as you have convergence in probability and expectation to different limits whereas in my question the convergence is to the same limit $\mu$.

Comment: You may try digging into the proof of UI + $o_P(1)$ implies $O(1)$ in $E$.

Comment: I don't see how that can be true. Uniform integrability + $o_p(1)$ implies   uniform integrability + convergence in probability which implies convergence in expectation, whereas $O(1)$ means we don't have convergence in expectation. See Theorem 5.12 in Introduction to Statistical Limit Theory by Polansky for proof that UI + convergence in probability implies convergence in expectation.

Comment: $O(1)$ simply means bounded.  what you cited is common knowledge.  $o(1)$ implies $O(1)$, so that's *a fortiori* true.  I put $O(1)$ instead of $o(1)$ so as to correspond to your question body.  But that's not my main point.  In the classical proof (say, Thm 1 in [this MIT OCW notes](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-436j-fundamentals-of-probability-fall-2018/lecture-notes/MIT6_436JF18_lec19.pdf)) for the well-known fact that you've mentioned, try modifying $$E[Y_n] = \dots \text{($Y_n$ split by $\{Y_n>\epsilon\}$)}\le\epsilon+E[Y_n 1_\{Y_n>\epsilon\}]$$

Comment: Consider $Y_n = X_n - \mu$.  Now you want to change $E[Y_n]$ to $E[n^{s} Y_n]$ as you want to determine $s>0$ such that $E[Y_n] = O(n^{-s})$.  You might want to adapt $\{Y_n \ge \epsilon\}$ to your given condition $Y_n = O_p(n^{-t})$ for some $t > 0$.  Since that's your question, I would like you to put some effort into it, and return to math.SE with your own attempts on this.